# Geocoding API question - best way to make 1.5mm calls

Tags: geocoding

I have a 1.5mm address list for which I need to retrieve latitude and longitude.  Is there any better way to do this than by calling the Geocoding API 1.5mm times?

Thanks for your help.

I've done a small test.  My solution will work but am not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I should add that I'm planning on calling the API via the available Python classes.